# Synchronized Operating Systems

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, synchronization

I'm a developer that primarily uses GCC for 99% all of my compilable-projects, so naturally, I end up developing on Linux/OS X first, and then porting via Cygwin/MinGW/blood-sweat-and-tears later to Windows platforms. Despite this, I still prefer using Windows 7 for other things, such as games, due to the support. Synchronizing data nowadays isn't that big of a deal--R-sync applications, cloud storage, things like https://www.synology.com/en-us/-- but is there a way to synchronize programs, systems configurations, i.e like images of the entire system?

I realize licensing conflicts can occur.

But take, for example, Windows. Right now, I have Win7 on my main PC, but I do most of my development on my Mac (laptop) or Ubuntu. I have a Windows 7 VM that's very handy on-the-fly on my Mac; VMware has seamlessly streamlined that process. Is there a way I can get my VM on my laptop to synchronize all changes with the Windows on my main PC (both of them are Windows 7 x64), and vice versa? If so, could this also be used for OS X?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)?  It's a partition and disk imaging/cloning program.